# Time Division Multiplexing [TDM] Arduino implementation

Tags: arduino

I have a bunch of half-duplex RFM23 RF modules, the problem is that I need two modules on each node to make a bi-directional communication.

I heard that I can make it act as full-duplex modules by using TDM algorithms, by doing so, I can decrease the cost of the project a lot.

but I can't find the proper resources in the internet.

any help or suggestions will be great.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.